# RApache memory usage

Tags: ubuntu, memory

I have a server with ubuntu 12.04 and it is installed Apache, PHP5, MySQL, and Apache module called RApache. I am working with grid data is processed dynamically.

Each time the user makes a request to the website page that makes the calculations of the grid dynamically, memory is allocated in the data and functions of the R Script

The problem that after each request is not freed up space in memory, and the script will allocate memory until the server does not support more, making it necessary to restart it.

Is there any way to erase the memory used by R after every request?

Comment: If you have found a memory leak, you should report that to the developers.

Answer (score 0):

I observed the same problem (on Ubuntu 14.04) with some WebApp running memory-intensive R-scripts on the server-side using Rapache/Xhr-Requests.

Did you check if the mpm_prefork mod is actually enabled (i.e. listed in /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/)?

I installed the module following instructions from http://rapache.net/manual.html but it was not enabled initially (just the mpm_event stuff).

So in the end simply running

```
    a2enmod mpm_prefork
```

(+ apache restart ) solved the problem for me.

Garbage collection should work just fine then (otherwise you could also try and tune paramerters in the mpm_prefork.conf).

P.s.: Of course I am aware there might be a ton of other sources for a memory-leak.